# Sort a DataTable by a specific column rather than the primary key

Tags: c#, database, sorting, datatable, dataset

I am pretty new to C# and I am trying to link my Access database to the program and manipulate it and then later write it into a text file.

However, my data is currently sorted based on the ID (which is the primary key).
I would like to sort it based on Last Name and then do the manipulation because when I use "foreach(DataRow drr in dra)" the rows are retrieved in the order of the IDs.

[dra->Data Rows]

I would like to access the rows after they have been sorted but I am not sure of how to do it. The following is my code.

```
OleDbCommand myAccessCommand = new OleDbCommand(strAccessSelect, myAccessConn11);
OleDbDataAdapter myDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(myAccessCommand);

myAccessConn11.Open();
myDataAdapter.Fill(myDataSet, "Personal_Data");
myAccessConn11.Close();

DataTableCollection dta = myDataSet.Tables;
DataRowCollection dra = myDataSet.Tables["Personal_Data"].Rows;

foreach (DataRow drr in dra)
{
    *Manipulation*
}
```

I tried using `myDataSet.Tables["Personal_Data"].DefaultView.Sort = "LastName DESC";` but it didn't work.

Is there any other way in which I can sort the rows in the table before accessing them?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Is `strAccessSelect` the sql for accessing your data? Do the ordering there.

Comment: After applying the default view sort you need to call .ToTable() to bring back the results with the DefaultView having been applied.

Comment: I had earlier tried the answer posted below but I was getting an exception because my column was labelled "Last Name". Now I removed the space to give it a try and it did work. It was indeed a simple solution but I wasn't sure of how I had to handle that exception on the String strAccessSelect.

@Ric- Yes, that's the sql query that i use. It's a select statement.

Comment: @Ahmed- Yea, I tried doing that too, but it wasn't storing the sorted table back. It still was giving me the unsorted rows when I tried accessing the DataTable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sort the rows in your "strAccessSelect" SQL query, e.g:

> SELECT Id, FirstName, LastName from MyTable ORDER BY LastName ASC;

Comment: Thanks Owen!
This was something that I tried doing much earlier. However, my column name was 'Last Name' with a space inbetween. I was getting an exception while I tried doing this then. Now I have renamed my column as 'LastName' and it works. So I was just wondering...Just out of curiosity - How would you rewrite the same select statement if my column name was Last Name and not LastName. Would I have to use any escape sequences?

Comment: You wrap the column names in square brackets e.g. [Last Name] . But it's best to avoid using spaces in your database column names.

Comment: Oh okay! Thanks a lot!!